# Rust bitwise into u8

Tags: rust, bit-manipulation

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
let result: u8 = opcode & 0xff;
```

the thing is `opcode & 0xff` will always return something in 0 -> 255 which would always fit in the u8 but the compiler raise the error `expected u8 but found u16`. Why did Rust raise the error?

Comment: Can you provide details about `opcode`? Does `let result: u8 = (opcode as u8) & 0xff;` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust doesn't cast between types implicitly, you have to be explicit about the cast using the `as` keyword:

```
let result = opcode as u8;
```

Note that you can omit the AND operator, the `as` keyword will automatically truncate the number when converting from a larger type.